# Is there an equivalent to Delphi's formatfloat?

Tags: go, format

Is there any package or method that replicates Delphi's [formatfloat method](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=formatfloat)?

Examples of the intended output when given 1234.567:

```
##### : 1235
00000 : 01235
0     : 1235
#,##0 : 1,235
,0    : 1,235

0.#### : 1234.567
0.0000 : 1234.5670
```

Edit:

The formatting masks would still need to be in the same format as Delphi  (preferably, can be parsed and treated if need be), as they are present in an external file and it needs to be compatible with both.

Comment: I don't know if anyone's written a Delphi style formatter, but the standard [`fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) has standard printf-style formatting.

Comment: @JimB I've considered that and will do that if no other solution is found, but that would require parsing the original mask (masks would be used as they are in Delphi) and converting it to a compatible format. I'm also unsure if `fmt` can support the masks as they are.

Comment: Printf supports padding, width and precision, it just doesn't use "masks" like you have here. The only thing it doesn't directly support is comma insertion. If you want to use this special mask notation, you need to find or write a package that does so.